# sql Joining on same table but different column

Tags: sql, join, trim

**Contacts**

```
telephone1     telephone2
---------------------------
+271566681     NULL
+276445884     +271679161
+275684835     NULL
NULL           +276496136
```

**tFormat**

```
operator     range
-------------------
MTN          +2764
Vodacom      +2716
```

Expected results

```
TELEPHONE1     OPERATOR     TELEPHONE2     OPERATOR
---------------------------------------------------
+271666681     Vodacom      NULL           NULL
++276445884    MTN          +271679161     Vodacom
 NULL          NULL         +276496136     MTN
```

Current results

```
TELEPHONE1     OPERATOR     TELEPHONE2     OPERATOR
---------------------------------------------------
+271666681     Vodacom      NULL           NULL
+276445884     MTN          +271679161     NULL
 NULL          NULL         +276496136     NULL
```

The query displays telephone numbers and operator for t1 but only displays the telephone number and not the operator for t2. There is no relation between the two tables

```
select    
    c.telephon1, t1.operator
    c.telephone2, t2.operator
from
    Contacts as c 
left join 
    tFormat as t1 on left(c.telephone1, 5) = t1.range
left join 
    tFormat as t2 on left(c.telephone2, 5) = t2.NUMBER_RANGE
```

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.  Your join logic seems to indicate that there is a relationship between the two tables.

Comment: which means t2 is not properly joined with t1 (logical error in join).please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: your current query gives your expected result, i tried it,

Answer (score 1):

Below are the results for the test data which you provided, query is same as yours and I have added NVL clause in join condition as there were null telephone numbers.

```
with t1 as
(
select '+271566681' as telephone1, null as telephone2 from dual
union
select '+276445884' as telephone1, '+271679161' as telephone2 from dual
union
select '+275684835' as telephone1, NULL as telephone2 from dual
union
select NULL as telephone1, '+276496136' as telephone2 from dual
)
,t2 as 
(
select 'MTN' as opetr, '+2764' as rnge from dual
union
select 'Vodacom' as opetr, '+2716' as rnge from dual
)

select
t1.telephone1, t22.opetr,
t1.telephone2, t23.opetr
from t1 
left outer join t2 t22 on substr(nvl(t1.telephone1, '00000'),1,5) = t22.rnge
left outer join t2 t23 on substr(nvl(t1.telephone2, '00000'),1,5) = t23.rnge;

NULL    NULL    +276496136  MTN
+276445884  MTN +271679161  Vodacom
+271566681  NULL    NULL    NULL
+275684835  NULL    NULL    NULL

Your query would be -
    select
    t1.telephone1, t22.operator,
    t1.telephone2, t23.operator
    from Contacts t1 
    left outer join tFormat t22 on substr(nvl(t1.telephone1, '00000'),1,5) = t22.range
    left outer join tFormat t23 on substr(nvl(t1.telephone2, '00000'),1,5) = t23.range;

Note - There are issue with the test data which you have provided
> Table has 4 records but output has 3 records
> we don't have telephone1 number starting with +2716, but your output has one
> There is record in output which starts with ++, which is not there in your test data.
```

Comment: there's thousands of numbers. this is the long way of doing it, is there no shorter way

Comment: Since i didn't want to create these tables in db, i have used CTE and hard code the values which you have given. You don't have to do that.

Comment: Added query as well, It will be helpful if you can up vote if the answer was helpful

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
select c.telephone1, t1.operator,
       c.telephone2, t2.operator
from Contacts  c left join 
     tFormat t1
     on left(c.telephone1, 5) = t1.range left join 
     tFormat t2
     on left(c.telephone2, 5) = t2.range
where t1.range is not null or t2.range is not null;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2072c4ba353556cdd88c494a8e68521d) is a db<>fiddle.